# How to dynamically construct attribute names in Sunspot searchable block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

My search includes the ability to scope a query by a price range, the day of the week, and a guest count.

However, the price is different on each day of the week, and the price changes (not linearly) by the number of guests. The best way I can think of to index the data is to create a different field for each day/guest combo, e.g.,

```
searchable do
  integer :price_sunday_2_guests do
    price(:sunday, 2)
  end
  integer :price_sunday_3_guests do
    price(:sunday, 3)
  end

  ...

  integer :price_monday_2_guests do
    price(:monday, 2)
  end

  ... 

  # and so on...

end
```

Obviously, I don't want to type all that in. I want to construct those attributes in the searchable blocks. More like:

```
searchable do
  Date::DAYNAMES.each do |day_name|
    day = DateTime.strptime(day_name, '%A')
    (guests_min..guests_max).each do |guests|
      sym = (day_name.downcase + '_' + guests.to_s + 'guests_price_abs_max').to_sym
      integer sym do
        price(day_name, guests)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I get the following exception:
NoMethodError: undefined method `guests_min' for #<Sunspot::DSL::Fields:0x000001080bdcf0>

It does not complain about the constant Date::DAYNAMES.

It seems that Sunspot tries to interpret any method token as a field. Which, I suppose would even make sense if I understood it better.

So, my question, is there a smart way for me to do this? Do I need to just hardcode a range and let my price method return an empty value? Is there some mechanism available in the searchable block I'm not aware of?

Comment: Could you provide the code where guests_min and guests_max variables/methods are defined?

Comment: Did you try hard-coding `guests_min` and `guests_max` and it did not work too?